# Detecting the layout of an internal Apple hardware keyboard

Tags: swift, macos, keyboard, hardware, macos-carbon

Is there an API or a method for detecting which of the three main keyboard layouts – `ANSI`, `ISO`, or `Japanese` – a Mac notebook uses?

After fairly extensive research, I could not find any information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After countless hours of searching and digging through dusty manuals, I finally found a way to determine physical keyboard layout types attached to the Mac.

By using ancient `Carbon` APIs, you can call `KBGetLayoutType` in combination with `LMGetKbdType` to return the desired constants. This amazingly still works in macOS Monterey.

To anyone whose looking for a solution in the future, here it is using Swift 5.5:

```
import Carbon

// Determine the physical keyboard layout type.
// macOS recognizes three keyboard types: ANSI, JIS (Japan), and ISO (Europe).

let physicalKeyboardLayoutType = KBGetLayoutType(Int16(LMGetKbdType()))
switch physicalKeyboardLayoutType {
case _ where physicalKeyboardLayoutType == kKeyboardJIS:
    print("JIS")
case _ where physicalKeyboardLayoutType == kKeyboardISO:
    print("ISO")
default:
    print("ANSI")
}
```